# Empty PHP POST Variables

Tags: php, apache

### Background

Web-based contact form.

### Problem

The `$_POST` array is empty. When errors are enabled, no errors (except empty array values) are found. The code was tested and working at one point, then left untouched until I posted this question. The host might have performed an upgrade.

### Software

- PHP 5.2.17
- Apache 2.0.63
- SSI

### HTML Form

The HTML form is as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" id="commentForm">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="64" /><br />

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="320" /><br />

  <label for="message">Message</label>
  <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="40" id="Message"></textarea><br />

  <label for="human">40 + 2 =</label>
  <input type="text" name="human" id="human" size="10" maxlength="3" /><br />

  <p align="center">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-button" />
  </p>
</form>
```

### PHP Code

The following code is called when the form is submitted:

```
$reason = 'default';

error_reporting( 0 );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
ini_set( 'register_globals', 0 );
ini_set( 'allow_url_fopen', 0 );
ini_set( 'expose_php', 0 );
ini_set( 'magic_quotes_gpc', 0 );

function not_contacted() {
  global $reason;

  // Redirects to computer, name, email, or message.
  //
  header( 'Location: ../error-'.$reason.'.shtml' );
}

function wms_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  not_contacted();
  return true;
}

function wms_shutdown() {
  if( is_null( $e = error_get_last() ) === false ) {
    not_contacted();
  }
}

set_error_handler( "wms_error_handler" );
register_shutdown_function( 'wms_shutdown' );

$name = trim( stripslashes( $_POST["name"] ) );
```

### Logging

`echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];` == `GET`

`print_r( $_GET );` == `Array ( )`

`print_r( $_POST );` == `Array ( )`

`print_r( $_REQUEST );` ==

```
Array ( [__utma] => 181723617.1357984856.1311884601.1313715852.1313720411.12 [__utmz] => 181723617.1313720411.12.10.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=jigo [__utmc] => 181723617 [__utmb] => 181723617.3.10.1313720411 ) `
```

`file_get_contents('php://input')` == Empty

### Questions

1. What could be causing the PHP POST variable values to be empty?
2. Why is the `POST` method being transmogrified into a `GET` method?

I think it is a php.ini or httpd.conf conflict, but cannot be sure (it is a hosted domain).

Thank you.

### Update

The following test works.

*test.shtml*

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*test.php*

```
<?
echo $_POST["test"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following line from the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.whitemagicsoftware.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue.

The problem was the data were posted to the http url, but there was a redirection to the https version of the url. Datas in $_POST are lost during the redirect.

I hope this can help others