# empty $_POST variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know most people had this problem and many asked here but no solution seems to work for me. I have tried increasing the `post_max_size` etc. in `php.ini`, I found a solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116352/empty-php-post-variables) that was to remove this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.whitemagicsoftware.com/$1 [R=301,L]` from `.htaccess` file but I can not find any `.htaccess` file in my `xampp` folder anywhere.
I am looking for a solution for almost two days , tried changing the code but nothing worked for me. I also tried using `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` but the result is same. I can see the values of variables being sent using `firebug` but my variables are empty.
Any help would be appreciated .
This is my code

```
<?php require ("database_connect.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
    Password : <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">   
    </form>

    <?php
    //$name=$password="" ;
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" and isset($_POST["login"])){

            $name = testInput($_POST['name']);
            $password = testInput($_POST['password']);
            echo $name."<br>";
        }//if ends here

        //testInput function
        function testInput($data){
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        }//testInput ends here


        if(isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])){
        echo "Name is ".$name ."- Pass is ".$password."<br>";
        if($result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users" )){           

            //print "rows are ".$result->num_rows."<br>";//number of rows

            if($result && mysqli_affected_rows($conn) >= 1){//If query was successfull and it has 1 or more than 1 result
            //echo "you are logged in<br>";
                ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result));

                echo "$row[0] is ".$row[0]."- $row[1] is ".$row[1]."<br>";
                if( $row[0]==$name && $row[1]==$password){
                    echo "Welcome";
                } 
            }//if ends here


            /* free result set */
            $result->close();
        }       
        else {
            print "Wrong Credentials "."<br>";
            die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        }

        //close connection
        $conn->close();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: oh, and `affected_rows` on a select is pointless. you're not AFFECTING (e.g. changing) any rows. you want mysqli_num_rows() instead to see who many rows where found/matched.

Comment: try having testInput return $data

Comment: @Adamnick:  Glad to hear you guys figured it out.  Either you or Kisaragi you should post your solution as an answer and accept it to more clearly indicate to others that you've solved it.

Comment: @Adamnick (Don't forget to accept it with the green checkmark below the vote count. :) )

Comment: @Aaron it says i can accept it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been resolved , there was a problem in my testInput($data) function.
This is the updated code that works plus a simple tip for future users ,always closely see your code , you will find the problem :)

```
<?php require ("database_connect.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
    Password : <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">   
    </form>

    <?php
    //$name=$password="" ;
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" and isset($_POST["login"])){

            $name = testInput($_POST["name"]);
            $password = testInput($_POST["password"]);

        }//if ends here

        //testInput function
        function testInput($data){
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

            return $data;
        }//testInput ends here


        if(isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])){

        if($result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' and password='$password'" )){

            if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1){//If query was successfull and it has 1 or more than 1 result

            echo "Welcome <br>";

            }//if ends here
            else {
            echo "Wrong Credentials <br>";
        }

            /* free result set */
            $result->close();
        }       
        else {
            echo "Wrong Credentials <br>";
            die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        }

        //close connection
        $conn->close();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>">

to 

<form method="POST" action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess htmlspecialchars() should be run before the stripslashes() or just delete the htmlspecialchars() in file. :)

```
    function testInput($data){
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);

        return $data;
    }
```